# how to sort data in postgres order by a to z then 0 to 9

Tags: postgresql

Here is my data:

```
Bensus Data 1872 1 Bombay
Bensus Data 1872 2 Bombay
Bensus Data 1872 Bombay
Bensus Data 1872 Combay
```

PostgreSQL by default numerals having higher priority I need data like:

```
Bensus Data 1872 Bombay
Bensus Data 1872 1 Bombay
Bensus Data 1872 2 Bombay
Bensus Data 1872 Combay
```

see no specific structure in data.

Comment: Where would "Bombay Bensus Data 1872 1 Combay" go?  I suspect that the ordering is not quite as simple as your description.

Comment: sir plz see the question once again..i changed the data

Comment: Why would the order be B then 1 and 2 and then C ? it doesn't make muche sense to me. Otherwise if it does because you have "B" after 1 and 2, I think you're going to need a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) to sort without numbers.  Here, I'm replacing any number (`[0-9]`) with the tilde character (`~`), which sorts [below any letter](http://www.asciitable.com). The **g**lobal `'g'` flag means replace all matches instead of just the first one.

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        regexp_replace(col1, '[0-9]', '~', 'g')
,       col1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb56a/4/0)